# MongoDB: command SON([('listCollections', 1), ('cursor', {})]) on namespace cuckoo.$cmd failed: Unsupported OP_QUERY command

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, cuckoo

I am trying to connect cuckoo and mongodb. I download mongodb and cuckoo. When I write cuckoo command to start cuckoo it gives error:

`2023-01-09 04:21:22,515 [cuckoo] CRITICAL: CuckooCriticalError: Unable to connect to MongoDB: command SON([('listCollections', 1), ('cursor', {})]) on namespace cuckoo.$cmd failed: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: listCollections. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal. In order to operate Cuckoo as per your configuration, a running MongoDB server is required.`

I am using ubuntu 22.04.
`mongod --version`
`db version v6.0.3 Build Info: { "version": "6.0.3", "gitVersion": "f803681c3ae19817d31958965850193de067c516", "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022", "modules": [], "allocator": "tcmalloc", "environment": { "distmod": "ubuntu2204", "distarch": "x86_64", "target_arch": "x86_64" } }`

I am trying to reinstall mongodb and chown command but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wire Protocol documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#mongodb-wire-protocol):

> OP_QUERY
> Deprecated in MongoDB 5.0. Removed in MongoDB 5.1.

So you will need to either:

- upgrade the driver used by Cuckoo to one compatible with the version of MongoDB you are running
- install MongoDB version 5.0 or older